# fatal error: bmpfile.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, include, bmp, include-path

I have installed the libbmp library from this link https://code.google.com/p/libbmp/ and I have made all the required steps to complete with the installation.
When I try to use it, by including the bmpfile.h like the example on the download page:

```
#include <bmpfile.h>
```

I get this error:

```
fatal error: bmpfile.h: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install the `libbmp` stuff to the correct locations?

Comment: I extracted the file, and followed the usual instructions. ./configure, make, etc

Comment: This won't solve the root of your problem, but you can put bmpfile.h in the same folder as the program you are trying to include it in and then just call `#include "bmpfile.h"` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably it was installed to `/usr/local/include` and your compiler doesn't look in that location. To fix this, you should set your `CPATH` variable to point there:

```
CPATH=/usr/local/include
export CPATH
```

This is typically done in your `.bashrc` or similar, or in your IDE if you're using one.

For more info check your compiler manual.